# React Native expo react-native-gesture-handler not working at all

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-native-gesture-handler

I am facing this weird problem. There is simply not activity on swipe of the Swipeable element. This might be a version issue as I have seen few samples available on git that are working having a different version but can't use that as they are many years old. Please help with this.

Here's the package.json >

```
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.0"
```

Here's the code

```
import {Text,View,TouchableHighlight,StatusBar as SB} from 'react-native';
import {MaterialCommunityIcons} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { FlatList, Swipeable } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const messages = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "T1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "T2",
  }, {
    id: 3,
    title: "T3",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "T4",
  }
]

const generateColor = () => {
 const colors = ['tomato','green','purple','yellow'];
 return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
}
export default function App() {  
return (
  <FlatList
    style={{
      flex:1,
      paddingTop:SB.currentHeight
    }}
    data={messages}
    keyExtractor={message=>message.id.toString()}
    renderItem={message=>
    <Swipeable
      renderRightActions={()=>
      <View style={{
        width:70,
        backgroundColor:'red',
        height:70
      }}>

      </View>
    }>
      <TouchableHighlight
          underlayColor={generateColor()}
        onPress={()=>console.log("touched",message.item.title)}>
        <View style={{
          padding:20,
        }}>
          <Text>
            {message.item.title}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </Swipeable>
    }
    ItemSeparatorComponent={()=><View style={{
      width:'100%',
      height:1,
      backgroundColor:'black'
    }}></View>}
  >

  </FlatList>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's embarassing as there was no compilation error, I forgot to import react for this functional component.....as the third party components were requiring that on runtime....

So with that, its fixed.